# How to use webcam with Python and Pygame with Windows? vidcap.Error: Cannot set capture resolution

Tags: python, pygame, video-capture

So I downloaded the windows wheel for Video Capture in my Pygame.  But when I create a webcam instance I'm getting the error below.  The code worked well until I started to implement the camera module.  I've seen very few answers and they were from 2013.  I was hoping Pygame would've improved on Windows more since then, but it's most likely me that's causing the problem.  Any suggestions?

```py
import pygame
import pygame.camera

pygame.init()
# https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#videocapture need to get the VideoCapture whl
pygame.camera.init()

webcam = pygame.camera.Camera(0, (640, 480), "RGB")
webcam.start()

pygame.display.set_caption("S.H.A.N.E.")
icon = pygame.image.load("SHANE pic.jpg")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
background = pygame.image.load("SHANE pic.jpg")
# (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen_width = 800
screen_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

running = True
while running:
    # STARTING POINT (L/R, T/B), ENDING POINT (L/R, T/B)
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    img = webcam.get_image()
    screen.blit(img, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Here's the error I'm getting.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:/Users/Notebook/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/Gui2.py", line 10, in <module>
>
> webcam = pygame.camera.Camera(0, (640, 480), "RGB")
>
> File "C:\Users\Notebook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-<packages\pygame\_camera_vidcapture.py", line 60, in __init__
>    self.dev.setresolution(width, height)
> vidcap.Error: Cannot set capture resolution.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
webcam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(640,480))
```

You do not place the coordinates/size/scale of the camera where you have placed them, that is reserved for the file input.
Cheers!
Docs:
https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/CameraIntro.html

Comment: It didn't work for me.  The "/dev/video0" is a linux camera location.  When I run the camera.list, my camera is just located at 0.  I ran through the documentation and it didn't work for me either.

Comment: It prints 0, it means you dont have a camera maybe, or your script isnt getting permissions it needs to access the camera.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to check what camera(s) you have.

```
pygame.camera.init()
camlist = pygame.camera.list_cameras()
print(camlist)
```

For example, mine prints ['FaceTime HD Camera']. Then you go

```
cam = pygame.camera.Camera('FaceTime HD Camera', (640,480))
```

If you mean yours prints ['0'], I wonder if you can fix the problem by simply changing 0 to '0'.